# Projects load failed in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

When I am opening a .sln in Visual Studio 2010, projects are loading properly. But when I open the same solution with Visual Studio 2015 (Professional with Update 1), projects are not getting loaded with the error (load failed). This is shown below:

[image: Projects not loading]

Can anyone suggest the solution for this?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Recently I had the same problem and it was because I didn't have the proper .net sdk installed in my pc (it was a lower version than the one that was installed with VS). So after getting it, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 24):

I experienced this issue for different reasons , but deleting all of the .vs folders ( there was one at the solution level and some projects had their own ) worked for me .

How To: 
Close the solution , delete all the .vs folders , reopen the solution .

Comment: Does not work for me.

Answer (score 18):

I've already had this problem and in my case I solved it by executing VS as Administrator.

Comment: thats it! 2 hours research than i found your post, thank you so much

Comment: How do you do this on Mac?

Comment: Hey @d13, 
[Here](https://www.wikihow.com/Open-Applications-With-Root-Privileges-on-a-Mac)  you can find some information on how to run an application with root privilege on Mac, this is not the exact answer for your question, but I think it can help you.

Answer (score 15):

Try the following:

1. Open the `Output` window (`View`->`Output` or `Ctrl+Alt+O`).
2. Then right-click one of the failed projects and select `Reload Project`.

The `Output` window will now show a more detailed error message.

Comment: Great general tip, didnt solve my problem, but lead to a solution. thx.

Answer (score 11):

Try deleting .suo & .user files.

---

http://www.howtosolutions.net/2013/02/solving-project-file-error-could-not-find-part-of-the-path-with-visual-studio/

> For those who receive this error but did not move projects around
>
> Try deleting .suo files in your solution folder. Solution User Option
>   file is a binary file which contains various user information and
>   settings such as location of the breakpoints.
>
> If that didn't help try also to delete .user file. If you have trouble
>   finding .suo file
>
> In Visual Studio 2015 (also in Community Edition), the .suo file is
>   located inside a hidden .vs folder in solution folder. Since both .vs
>   folder and .suo file have hidden attribute applied to them, you have
>   to reveal them using using File Explorer by changing folder options to
>   “show hidden files, folders and drives”. How to get to this option in
>   File Explorer depends on the version of Windows:
>
> - In Windows 7, option is located under Organize > Folder and search options.
> - in Windows 8, it is located under View tab > Options > Change folder and search options.
> - in Windows 10, it is the same as in Windows 8.

Answer (score 8):

I opened the .sln (MySolutionName.sln) file with Notepad++ and edited the below parts. I had 3 projects in my solution:

```
MyProject1Name, MyProject2Name, MyProject3Name
```

1. `Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MyProject1Name", "MySolutionName\MyProject1Name.csproj", "{D9FA9D42-71F3-459E-9643-426F002713EE}"
   EndProject`
2. `Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MyProject2Name.Service", "MyProject2Name\MyProject2Name.csproj", "{173F0709-90E3-48B9-AA06-4AEC9957AFED}"
   EndProject`
3. `Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MyProject3Name", "MyProject3Name\MyProject3Name.csproj", "{B5F4ADAC-7C37-4A2C-B15A-56C50F3BF7C9}"
   EndProject`

then everything worked properly and the projects load successfully.

Comment: thanks, changing the paths solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

You may need to correct the Projects Path to match new environment. Please see below post to see how to do it.

http://www.howtosolutions.net/2013/02/solving-project-file-error-could-not-find-part-of-the-path-with-visual-studio/

Comment: All the project paths are correct. Because with VS 2010 the projects are loading properly. The problem is only with VS 2015

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue where a colleague could not open the solution that contained many projects. I had previously migrated the solution from VS2013 to VS2015 and I had no issues with projects loading once opening the solution.

The fix was to install SSDT for VS2015
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt#ssdt-for-visual-studio-2015

This allowed for all the projects to load correctly within the solution.

Answer (score 1):

deleting .vs files worked for me also. I can now able to rename project file. I am using VS 2017

Answer (score 1):

Our project was configured to use Local IIS and in our case it was needed to run Visual Studio as Administrator and only then the project loaded...

Answer (score 1):

1- Open .sln file in notepad

2- Change path/name of your project

[image]

3-Open Visual studio

4- Right click project and Remove.

5- Right click solution and add project again.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by simply update the string path inside .sln file

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file which failed to load and reload it ,it worked in mine case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a web-project, solved it by deleting applicationhost.config from the .vs\config folder.

I recently enabled SSL for that project, and then disabled it again by undoing the changes from another solution, I suspect its related to that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a global.json file with a defined dotnet core sdk version that wasn't installed.

I removed the global.json and it worked.

I then looked up my sdk versions and returned the global.json but updated the version in it. Alternatively, you can just install the required sdk.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with project loading failed, like this:

[image]

The **first** thing you need to do is to fix all of the other issues you are having.
The **next** step is to check the project .csproj file.

[image]

In my case, the issue was `<TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>`
You mind have **another issue**, just carefully check the file.

[image]

So I **deleted the issue line** and **reloaded** the project, and it works just fine every time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this issue occurred after I renamed and moved around a few projects in my solution. What worked in my case was a simple removal of those project files and then re-adding them from the 'Solution Explorer'. Sharing a handy [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-fix-project-file-could-not-be-loaded-issue-after-rename-project-in-asp/) with screenshots that might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio > right click > Run as administrator > open the project
this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who tried all these options and can't fix the problem. Here's my suggestion:

1. Make a backup
2. Close Visual Studio.
3. Go to the .user path and delete it
4. Open Visual Studio as an administrator
5. Clean the solution
6. Build and run the project again

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the change of .Net core version of the project while i was not working

Answer (score 0):

If your project is hosted on IIS

Note: To all the configurations will be in the project file and to open that: right-click the .csproj file in solution explorer and click on "edit project file" and follow the below steps.

Ensure that in your project file "< Use IIS >false</Use IIS >" tag is True like : "< Use IIS >true</Use IIS >".

Try to reload Project.

If Still not project didn't get loaded:

Remove the IIS Hosted Link from the project file:"< IIS Url>https://hostedlink.com:447/</IIS Url>"  make this  Tag empty like: "< IIS Url ></IIS  Url >"
and reload the project.

Answer (score 0):

1)Install the correct .Net SDK
2) Open command prompt and check (dotnet --info)
3)Restart the pc
4)Run Visual Studio as Administrator
5)Do Right Clicking on Solution Explorer and click Reload

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Right click on on the project which was failed and  select reload option from context menu, The screen will pop up which is related to permission, uncheck the check box and continue. It is noticed that initialization and loading of project will happen properly

Answer (score -4):

Please try with any of this VS2015/2019