# Visual Studio : "Load operation failed"

Tags: macos, visual-studio, github

Recently i switched from windows to macOS.
Before being on mac i made a site with dot net core 5.0
Except that since I arrived on Mac I can no longer open my project. I have the following message:[Error in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMeQ1.png)

I look forward to all your answers.

sorry for my english, i use google translate ^^

Comment: Have you tried this question's answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201920/projects-load-failed-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error message, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: This is already the complete error message.This is also why I am coming to you because I do not even know the origin of the problem.